# Lattice of self-adjoint bounded functionals on C*-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, operator-algebras, lattice-orders, signed-measures, banach-lattices

When it comes to real-valued signed measures on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{B})$, there’s a lattice structure given by
\begin{align*}
(\mu \lor \nu) (A) & = \sup \{ \mu (A \cap B) + \nu (A \setminus B ) : B \in \mathcal{B} \} , \\
(\mu \land \nu) (A) & = \inf \{ \mu (A \cap B) + \nu (A \setminus B ) : B \in \mathcal{B} \} .
\end{align*}
Is there an analogous way to take lattice operations on the (real) space of self-adjoint bounded linear functionals on a C*-algebra?

Comment: If this is possible it is probably rather in the von Neumann algebra setting.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy Well this example shows it’s at least possible for commutative C*-algebras, since the self-adjoint bounded functionals on $C(X)$ for $X$ locally compact are exactly the signed measures (via Riesz representation theorem)